# Optimisation algorithm

Tags: matlab, gradient-descent

I recently started learning MATLAB and tried to realise an optimisation algorithm (gradient descending). But something went wrong: I always get false results/

Here is a part of my code:

```
%P = (a, b)exp(-a*alpha_1(i)/2)+exp(-b*alpha_2(i)/2) 
%a+b<=6, a>0, b>0 
%alpha_1, alpha_2 - some real numbers

    r0=1; a(1)=6; b(1)=6;j=2;
    while j<=120
        dPda = -alpha_1(i)/2*exp(-a(j-1)*alpha_1(i)/2);
        dPdb = -alpha_2(i)/2*exp(-b(j-1)*alpha_2(i)/2);
        ll = 1/(dPda*dPda+dPdb*dPdb);
        a(j)= a(j-1)-ll*dPda;
        b(j)= b(j-1)-ll*dPdb;
        r=r/120;
        if (r<0.1)
            break
        else
            j=j+1
        end
        
    end
```